# Why am I getting a CSRF token missing error when the token is there?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs3

I have a Vue app and I am making requests to a Django Rest Framework endpoint, well a few. It was working fine yesterday and I was able to submit and save content. Today I keep getting the same error:
`CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing`.

But if I look in the dev tools I see this:

```
|csrftoken|“wzWBo6N66F1HTp2To67We5GppNWfbXdm”|
|sessionid|“1vq4vj73b1b6l80gt2ckba6zwxqj8wwu”|
```

So how is it missing if it is right there?

Second question:

What is the use of this setting if no matter what it still gives you a CSRF error?

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (“localhost:8080”,“127.0.0.1:8080”)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [“http://localhost:8080”, “http://*.127.0.0.1”, “http://127.0.0.1:8080”,“http://192.168.1.44:8080”,]
```

Here are my Axios settings:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and here is the Vue template sending the data:

```
<template>
  <div class="component" id="editAccount">
    <div class="editHeader w60 auto">
      <p>
        <b>Please note:</b> If you change your password or email, you will be
        sent an email to confirm the change. If the changed is confirmed by
        clicking on the link, or by using the code in the email, the email
        and/or password will change. Otherwise it will remain the same.
      </p>
    </div>
    <form id="editAccountForm" class="form w50 auto">
      <fieldset>
        <h4 class="label">First name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="first_name"
          id=""
          placeholder="First name"
          v-model="first_name"
        />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h4 class="label">Last name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="last_name"
          id=""
          placeholder="Last name"
          v-model="last_name"
        />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h4 class="label">Email</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          id=""
          placeholder="Email"
          v-model="user_email"
        />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="mb10">
        <h4 class="label">Password</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="password"
          id=""
          placeholder="Password"
          v-model="password"
        />
        <p class="smapp">
          You must enter your current password to update your account
        </p>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="checkWrap mb10" v-if="password.length > 0">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="nochange"
          id="notChanging"
          v-model="notChanging"
        />
        <label for="notChanging">I'm not changing my password</label>
      </div>
      <fieldset class="mb5" v-if="password.length > 0 && !notChanging">
        <h4 class="label">New Password</h4>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="new_password"
          id=""
          v-model="newpassword"
          @input="checkInputStrength"
          placeholder="New Password"
        />
      </fieldset>
      <div
        class="np-password-hint mb10"
        v-if="password.length > 0 && !notChanging"
      >
        <small>
          Password should be between 8 and 20 characters long and contain
          numbers and symbols.
        </small>
      </div>

      <h4 v-if="password.length > 0 && !notChanging">Password strength</h4>
      <div
        class="np-password-strength-indicator-container"
        v-if="password.length > 0 && !notChanging"
      >
        <div
          class="np-password-strength-indicator"
          :style="{
            backgroundColor: getIndicatorBackgroundColor(),
            width: getIndicatorWidth() + '%',
          }"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <fieldset v-if="password.length > 0 && !notChanging">
        <h4 class="label">Repeat Password</h4>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="confirmpassword"
          id=""
          v-model="confirmpassword"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
        />
      </fieldset>
      <p class="smapp" v-if="password.length > 0 && !notChanging">
        Once you click save an email will be sent with a link. You need to
        confirm the password change by clicking on the link. The link expires
        within 24 hours and your password will not be changed unless confirmed.
      </p>
    </form>
    <div
      class="buttonsWrap flex justC alignC w50 auto"
      v-if="!deleting && !showConfirm"
    >
      <button type="button" class="mr5 saveBtn" @click="saveAccount">
        Save
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="ml5 cancelBtn" @click="closeForm">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
    <DeleteAccount @closeform="deleting = false" v-if="deleting" />
    <div class="confirmBox fixed" v-if="showConfirm">
      <h2 class="label mb20">
        Are you sure you want to delete your account? This cannot be undone.
      </h2>
      <button class="mr5" @click="deleteAcc">Yes</button>
      <button class="saveBtn ml5" @click="showConfirm = false">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="deleteAcc center mt10" v-if="!deleting && !showConfirm">
      <p>
        To delete your account click
        <span @click="askConfirm">here</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount, ref, computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { useWagooStore } from "@/stores/wagoo";
import DeleteAccount from "./DeleteAccount";
const store = useWagooStore();
const account = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("account"));
const deleting = ref(false);
const showConfirm = ref(false);
const first_name = ref("");
const last_name = ref("");
const user_email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const newpassword = ref("");
const confirmpassword = ref("");
const emit = defineEmits(["closeform"]);
const answer = ref("");
const inputStrength = ref(0);
const notChanging = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
  first_name.value = account.first_name;
  last_name.value = account.last_name;
  user_email.value = account.email;
});

const inputContainsSpecialCharacters = () => {
  const specialCharacters = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\\|,.<>?~]/;
  return specialCharacters.test(newpassword.value);
};

const inputContainsNumbers = () => {
  const numbers = /\d/;
  return numbers.test(newpassword.value);
};
const checkInputStrength = () => {
  inputStrength.value = 0;

  const inputStrengthLengthCheck =
    newpassword.value && newpassword.value.length >= 8;
  const inputContainsSpecialChars = inputContainsSpecialCharacters();
  const inputContainsNum = inputContainsNumbers();

  if (inputStrengthLengthCheck) {
    inputStrength.value++;
  }
  if (inputContainsSpecialChars) {
    inputStrength.value++;
  }
  if (inputContainsNum) {
    inputStrength.value++;
  }
};

const getIndicatorBackgroundColor = () => {
  let color = "gray";
  switch (inputStrength.value) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      color = "red";
      break;
    case 2:
      color = "orange";
      break;
    case 3:
      color = "green";
      break;
    default:
      color = "gray";
  }
  return color;
};

const getIndicatorWidth = () => {
  return parseInt((inputStrength.value / 3) * 100).toString();
};

const closeForm = (data) => {
  emit("closeform", data);
};

async function saveAccount() {
  let current_email = account.email;
  let form = document.getElementById("editAccountForm");
  let formdata = new FormData(form);
  if (password.value === "") {
    store.messages.push("Password is required to update account");
    setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
  } else {
    if (inputStrength.value <= 1 && notChanging == true) {
      store.messages.push("Password is to weak please add special characters");
      setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
    }
    // not changing email or password
    if (
      user_email.value == current_email &&
      password.value != "" &&
      notChanging.value == true
    ) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.put(
          "/api/v1/users/" + account.id + "/u/",
          formdata
        );
        if (response.status == 200) {
          account.first_name = first_name.value;
          account.last_name = last_name.value;
          const updatedAccount = JSON.stringify(account);
          localStorage.setItem("account", updatedAccount);
          store.messages.push("Account updated successfully");
          setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
          let data = {
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
          };
          closeForm(data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        store.messages.push(error.response.data);
        setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
      }
      // changing password
    } else if (
      user_email.value == current_email &&
      password.value != "" &&
      notChanging.value == false
    ) {
      if (newpassword.value != confirmpassword.value) {
        store.messages.push("Password do not match");
        setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 3000);
      } else {
        try {
          const response = await axios.put(
            "/api/v1/users/" + account.id + "/u/",
            formdata
          );
          if (response.status == 200) {
            store.messages.push(
              "Email sent to confirm password change. Password will change once confirmed"
            );
            setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []));
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.response);
        }
      }

      // changing email
    } else if (
      user_email.value != current_email &&
      password.value != "" &&
      notChanging.value == true
    ) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.put(
          "/api/v1/users/" + account.id + "/u/",
          formdata
        );
        if (response.status == 200) {
          store.messages.push(
            "Email sent to confirm email change. Email will change once confirmed"
          );
          setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        store.messages.push(error.response.data);
        setTimeout(() => (store.messages = []), 5000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function askConfirm() {
  showConfirm.value = true;
}

async function deleteAcc() {
  deleting.value = true;
  showConfirm.value = false;
}
</script>
```

Here is the Django view handling the data:

```
class UpdateUser(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user

        first_name = request.data.get("first_name")
        last_name = request.data.get("last_name")
        current_email = request.data.get("email")
        current_password = request.data.get('password')
        new_password = request.data.get("new_password")
        confirm_password = request.data.get('confirmpassword')

        if not check_password(current_password, user.password):
            return Response("Password is not correct", status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        user_email = user.email

        # Change just password 
        if new_password and current_email == user_email:
            if new_password != confirm_password:
                return Response("Passwords do not match", status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            elif check_password(new_password, user.password):
                return Response({"message": "New password is same as the old, please choose another"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:                
                code = []
                numbers = range(6)
                for num in numbers:
                    code.append(randint(0, 9))
                confirm_code = "".join(str(e) for e in code) 
                from_email = "admin@wagoo.co.za"
                title = "Password"
                link = f"localhost:8000/confirm/{user.email}/"
                context = {"code": code, "link": link, "title":title}
                template = get_template("emails/confirm.html").render(context)
                subject = "You requested a password change, here is your code"
                message = "Your code"
                user.temp_pass = make_password(new_password)
                user.first_name = first_name
                user.last_name = last_name
                user.confirm_code = confirm_code
                user.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)                
                try:
                    send_mail(
                        subject,
                        message=message,
                        from_email=from_email,
                        recipient_list=[user.email],
                        html_message=template,
                    )
                    return Response("Password changed, mail sent", status=HTTP_200_OK)
                except:
                    return Response("Could not send mail", status=HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)

        # change just first name and last name
        elif not new_password and current_email == user_email:
            user.first_name =  first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.save()
            return Response("User updated", status=HTTP_200_OK)
        
        # change just email
        elif not new_password and current_email != user_email:
            exists = User.objects.filter(email=current_email).exists()
            if exists:
                return Response("That email is already in use. Please make sure and let us know if you find this suspicious.", status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else: 
                user.first_name =  first_name
                user.last_name = last_name     
                user.temp_email = current_email
                user.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)  
                code = []
                numbers = range(6)
                for num in numbers:
                    code.append(randint(0, 9))
                confirm_code = "".join(str(e) for e in code) 
                user.confirm_code = confirm_code
                from_email = "admin@wagoo.co.za"
                title = "Email"
                link = f"localhost:8000/confirm/{user.email}/"
                context = {"code": code, "link": link, "title":title}
                template = get_template("emails/confirm.html").render(context)
                subject = "You requested an email change, here is your code"
                message = "Your code from WAGOO"
                try:
                    send_mail(
                        subject,
                        message=message,
                        from_email=from_email,
                        recipient_list=[user.email],
                        html_message=template,
                    )
                    return Response("Email changed, mail sent", status=HTTP_200_OK)
                except:
                    return Response("Could not send mail")

        else:
            exists = User.objects.filter(email=current_email).exists()
            if exists:
                return Response("That email is already in use. Please make sure and let us know if you find this suspicious.", status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                user.first_name =  first_name
                user.last_name = last_name     
                user.temp_email = current_email
                user.temp_pass = confirm_password
                user.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)  
                code = []
                numbers = range(6)
                for num in numbers:
                    code.append(randint(0, 9))
                confirm_code = "".join(str(e) for e in code) 
                user.confirm_code = confirm_code
                from_email = "admin@wagoo.co.za"
                title = "Email &amp; Password"
                link = f"localhost:8000/confirm/{user.email}/"
                context = {"code": code, "link": link, "title":title}
                template = get_template("emails/confirm.html").render(context)
                subject = "You requested an email change, here is your code"
                message = "Your code from WAGOO"
                try:
                    send_mail(
                        subject,
                        message=message,
                        from_email=from_email,
                        recipient_list=[user.email],
                        html_message=template,
                    )
                    return Response("Email changed, mail sent", status=HTTP_200_OK)
                except:
                    return Response("Could not send mail")
```

Request Headers:

```
PUT /api/v1/users/22/u/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------190144762033513088291902453782
Content-Length: 668
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Cookie: csrftoken=wzWBo6N66F1HTp2To67We5GppNWfbXdm; sessionid=1vq4vj73b1b6l80gt2ckba6zwxqj8wwu
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2023 02:30:54 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.12
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, origin, Cookie
Allow: PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 45
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
access-control-allow-credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

cookies:

```
csrftoken   "wzWBo6N66F1HTp2To67We5GppNWfbXdm"
sessionid   "1vq4vj73b1b6l80gt2ckba6zwxqj8wwu"
```

Request payload:

```
-----------------------------190144762033513088291902453782
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first_name"


-----------------------------190144762033513088291902453782
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="last_name"


-----------------------------190144762033513088291902453782
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

cal@mail.com
-----------------------------190144762033513088291902453782
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

lekker1
-----------------------------190144762033513088291902453782
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nochange"

on
-----------------------------190144762033513088291902453782--
```

Response:

```
CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing.
```

Hope I included everything

UPDATE:

I restored a backup and that works fine and looking at the headers I see there is a X-CSRFToken in the working version. So why is the token not being included in the non-working version? What puts the token in the header? I presume Axios so why is it not including it I never changed any settings. How can I force it?

Comment: Share the form/view and the template.

Comment: I updated my question hope I included everything